# Why isn't my output in byte code? When using FileOutputStream and using the .getBytes method

Tags: java

This is the code that I'm using, when I run it and open the output file, I see Hello world saved.

Why is it like this?

```
public class Fileoutputstream {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        File file = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

        try {

            file = new File("output");
            if (!file.exists()) {                                 
               file.createNewFile();
            }                                   

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

            String textToSave = "Hello World";
            byte[] textToSaveBytes = textToSave.getBytes();
            fileOut.write(textToSaveBytes);

            fileOut.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: It appears you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what bytes are and how file storage works.  All files of all types are sequences of bytes;  it is up to an application, like a text editor, to decide how to interpret those bytes.

Comment: Im learning about byte streams and character streams, I figured if I run an fileoutputstream which is under byte streams, the result will be a type of machine code

Comment: So you want to see "Hello" in machine code, if I get this right? Edit your question to show the expected output.

Comment: _"Why isn't my output in byte code?"_  What would you expect to see if your output was in "byte code"?  What does "byte code" mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

The bytes you written into the file is actually the ASCII code string so no doubt your output file's a text file.
Most programs will treat file as 'text' if there is no non-text character in it, i.e NULL byte, control character etc..

Comment: So the getBytes is returning ASCII code, thank you sir

Comment: If the string, where you call `getBytes` on, contains ASCII chars, then yes, it's returning ASCII in bytes. If the string contains UTF characters, it will return the bytes for those characters.

Comment: _"So the getBytes is returning ASCII code"_ -- no, it is taking the UTF-16 values in the source string and _encoding_ them in the platform's default character set, which in the US would likely be ISO-8859-1, which is a _superset_ of ASCII.  Any UTF-16 characters that don't exist in the target character set get changed to the "default replacement" character.

Comment: The ASCII I was talking about is somewhat misleading. Like the above comment said it's likely that your default system charset is UTF-8 (or some other ASCII-compatible ones), and if that string passed to `getBytes` with no argument contains just only ASCII code then the bytes you get is equally 1-to-1 with the String's character.